# Vagrant not syncing with NFS

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am having an intermittent issue - as in, it was working yesterday, today its not.

Bascially i'm on macos and trying to use vagrant with nfs, the error i'm getting is:

```
Please add a host-only network to the machine (with either DHCP or a
static IP) for NFS to work.
```

However I do have a host-only network created using DHCP

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

I've tried changing it to an IP address instead of DHCP which I shouldn't need to do, but then it just never connects.

As I said I had this working yesterday and nothing has changed in the repo so I'm not really seeing why its not working today.

Happy to share whole vagrantfile if it will be useful?

Just to add, if I destroy the box fully and recreate it... it works perfectly.

Thanks
Kevin